# Show both tags and branches in Bitbucket under commits view

Tags: git, bitbucket

Yesterday I started using tags in git for the first time.
Now when I go to Commits/All branches in Bitbucket, it only shows the tags, whereas before, it had a branch name next to each commit.

[You can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFxIT.png), next to the "Merge branches 'develop' and 'release'" it only has a tag, it used to only omit "master" now it omits all branches(I have added in red what it should say)

I am looking to reenable that functionality, I want it to show both tags and branches there.

Answer (score 12):

In Bitbucket go to Commits. In the dropdown at the top of the page if you don't see the Show All link beside the dropdown, click on one of the branches in your list of branches in the dropdown. This will cause the Show All link to appear, just click on the Show All link and all your branch names will appear in the history below the dropdown.

All this does is change the url

**Before**
https://bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/commits/branch/master

**After**
https://bitbucket.org/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/commits/all

Comment: That doesn't include tags. Atlassian ignore tags across all Bitbucket Cloud UI. Pure product.